# Jquery page transition resets height

Tags: jquery-mobile, packery

I'm using packery to pack multiple pages and am using jquery mobile pagecontainer for the transitions. On each transition the packery layout gets collapsed. The height of my container div changes to 0.

How do I retain the packery layout on page transition.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Change position to absolute","what the hell is packery","this is a ridiculous question" ... Anything at all?

Comment: add relevant HTML and js code.